# Prestashop search slow after migrating from MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, prestashop, mariadb

After migrating Prestashop instance from MySQL to MariaDB filtered search queries are gotten slow. Here's an example of a such slow query.

```
SELECT
    fl.name feature_name,
    fp.id_feature,
    fv.id_feature_value,
    fvl.value,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_product) nbr,
    lifl.url_name name_url_name,
    lifl.meta_title name_meta_title,
    lifvl.url_name value_url_name,
    lifvl.meta_title value_meta_title,
    psi.price_min,
    psi.price_max,
    m.name
FROM
    ps_feature_product fp
INNER JOIN
    ps_product p
ON
    (p.id_product = fp.id_product)
LEFT JOIN
    ps_feature_lang fl
ON
    (
        fl.id_feature = fp.id_feature AND fl.id_lang = 2
    )
INNER JOIN
    ps_feature_value fv
ON
    (
        fv.id_feature_value = fp.id_feature_value AND(
            fv.custom IS NULL OR fv.custom = 0
        )
    )
LEFT JOIN
    ps_feature_value_lang fvl
ON
    (
        fvl.id_feature_value = fp.id_feature_value AND fvl.id_lang = 2
    )
LEFT JOIN
    ps_layered_indexable_feature_lang_value lifl
ON
    (
        lifl.id_feature = fp.id_feature AND lifl.id_lang = 2
    )
LEFT JOIN
    ps_layered_indexable_feature_value_lang_value lifvl
ON
    (
        lifvl.id_feature_value = fp.id_feature_value AND lifvl.id_lang = 2
    )
INNER JOIN
    ps_product_shop product_shop
ON
    (
        product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1
    )
INNER JOIN
    `ps_layered_price_index` psi
ON
    (
        psi.id_product = p.id_product AND psi.id_currency = 2 AND psi.id_shop = 1
    )
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_manufacturer` m
ON
    (
        m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer
    )
WHERE
    product_shop.`active` = 1 AND product_shop.`visibility` IN("both", "catalog") AND fp.id_feature = 9 AND p.id_product IN(
    SELECT
        id_product
    FROM
        ps_category_product cp
    INNER JOIN
        ps_category c
    ON
        (
            c.id_category = cp.id_category AND c.id_category = 13 AND c.active = 1
        )
) AND p.id_product IN(
SELECT
    id_product
FROM
    ps_feature_product fp
WHERE
    fp.`id_feature_value` = 39
) AND p.id_product IN(
SELECT
    id_product
FROM
    ps_feature_product fp
WHERE
    fp.`id_feature_value` = 18
) AND p.id_product IN(
SELECT
    id_product
FROM
    ps_feature_product fp
WHERE
    fp.`id_feature_value` = 13
) AND p.id_product IN(
SELECT
    id_product
FROM
    ps_feature_product fp
WHERE
    fp.`id_feature_value` = 44
) AND p.id_product IN(
SELECT
    id_product
FROM
    ps_feature_product fp
WHERE
    fp.`id_feature_value` = 3186
)
GROUP BY
    fv.id_feature_value
ORDER BY
    fv.position
```

What is interesting is that it gets a lot faster (4s vs 0.4s) if one of the multiple (nearly identical) subqueries in the WHERE clause is removed.

```
... AND
/*
-- removing any of the six product filters makes
-- the query a lot faster
p.id_product IN(
    SELECT
        id_product
    FROM
        ps_feature_product fp
    WHERE
        fp.`id_feature_value` = 18
)
*/
AND ...
```

Here's the EXPLAIN output for this query (without the modifications).

[image]

Is there's something obvious that needs to be changed somehow? All tables are already OPTIMIZEd with no improvement.

Comment: Why do you have 5 identical subqueries at the end? Can't you make just one subquery with `where fp.id_feature_value = 39 or fp.id_feature_value = 18` and so on?

Comment: The software that makes the queries is Prestashop

Answer (score 2):

You have several of these:

```
    AND  p.id_product IN (
        SELECT  id_product
            FROM  ps_feature_product fp
            WHERE  fp.`id_feature_value` = 39 )
```

which could be turned into this

```
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ps_feature_product
                  WHERE id_product = p.id_product
                    AND id_feature_value = 39 )
```

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is poorly optimized.

Be sure to have `INDEX(id_product, id_feature_value)`.

The reason for the difference in performance between MySQL and MariaDB is that several optimization improvements diverged in about 5.6.  They involve stuff relating to what you are doing.

Things like

```
        LEFT JOIN  ps_layered_indexable_feature_value_lang_value lifvl
               ON ( lifvl.id_feature_value = fp.id_feature_value
              AND   lifvl.id_lang = 2
```

need a composite `INDEX(id_feature_value, id_lang)` (in either order).  But I can guess from the `EXPLAIN` that you have such.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, there may be more advice.

I can't address your specific question because I don't know which line of the `EXPLAIN` corresponds to the removed clause.